# Check if button in specific area

Tags: c#, winforms

How to check the button is located in specific area, i have two button and user make an rectangle drawn by mouse. 
How can check if the button is located in the rectangle area to make an action if located true ?
This image from my Winform when make an rectangle contain my buttons, I want when find the buttons located in the rectangle area make an action
[image: This image from my Winform when make an rectangle contain my buttons, I want when find the buttons located in the rectangle area make an action]

Comment: Do you mean coordinate-wise (even if hidden or in a container), or based on some sort of selection action?

Comment: if it in the container make his action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [Contains Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kh3ee9e(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
if (_yourSelectionRectangle.Contains(new Rectangle(button4.Location, button4.Size))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Would this also take into account the container's coordinate system with relation to its parents'?

Comment: If you want a button's location relative to the panel's location just use this location: `panel1.Location + (Size)button1.Location`. This is perfectly legit, you can add a size to a point and convert point to size.